# how to create and append multiple rows using two loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i need to create a dataframe such that i have the output as follows

```
day hour cal_hr
1   6    106
1   7    107
1   8    108
..
..
1   24   124
..
7   1    701
7   2    702
..
..
7   24   724
```

i want to loop through day and then hour and then do a concat of day and hour. With preceding 0 for 106(say)

something like

```
for i in range(1,8):
    for j in range(6,25):
        df.append(i,j)
 df=pd.dataFrame(df)
```

can df.append create two variables simaltaneously

Comment: unfortunately i need to create a dataframe , so that i can merge it back with another table. Cal_hr can be create later on if i have day and hour created. coz it is just a concatenation of day and hour. id day = 1 and hour =6 then cal_hr = 106 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append to a list then convert to a dataframe. It would be much more efficient.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, j, 100*i+j) 
                    for i in range(1, 8) 
                    for j in range(6, 25)], 
                    columns=['day', 'hour', 'cal_hr'])

df.head()
Out[143]: 
   day  hour  cal_hr
0    1     6     106
1    1     7     107
2    1     8     108
3    1     9     109
4    1    10     110

df.tail()
Out[144]: 
     day  hour  cal_hr
128    7    20     720
129    7    21     721
130    7    22     722
131    7    23     723
132    7    24     724
```

Comment: hi ayhan, can this logic be extended , say i want to add another column 'week' which goes from 201501 to 201552  and then 201601 to 201652, can i do the following ?

*core_hours = pd.DataFrame([(i, j, k, 100*i+j) for i in range(1, 8) for j in range(start_hour, end_hour+1) for k in range(201601, 201652)],
                          columns = ['day', 'hour_i', 'week', 'hour'])*

but in that case how do i make the loop to restart from 1 when the week hits 201652 (say)

Comment: @Mukul Can you edit the example in your post to include the week column. I don't understand exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as fast or as intuitive as @ayhan's answer, but I think it's an interesting way to think about it.

```
day = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 8), name='day')
hour = pd.Series(np.arange(6, 25), name='hour')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(day * 100, hour), day, hour)
df = df.stack().rename('cal_hr').reset_index()
```

---

```
df.head()
```

[image]

```
df.tail()
```

[image]